# NPS daily survey data

Tags: confidence-interval, panel-data, survey-sampling, cross-section, net-promoter-score

I have daily surveys sent to users of several of my organization´s services, the surveys consists only on NPS question (How likely would recommend X? on a 0 to 10 scale), number of respondents vary by day and service.

I would like to get the NPS score and confidence interval for a service on a monthly scale. Is it ok to joust aggregate the data points and calculate CI as in a cross-sectional survey?

After calculating monthly NPS I would like to compare scores from different services. Wold this be a valid approach?

Supposing the number of respondents is equal or grater than the number of respondents required in a cross-sectional approach. Is this a valid way to obtain a representative sample of the users of such services over a month?

Finally I would like to compare the NPS of a service before and after some significant project is made to improve the service. Projects usually take a few months to implement and have a marked go-live date. Wold comparing the NPS of months after the improvement to the NPS before the improvement be valid?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Have you searched our site?  Look for https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=nps.

Comment: Yes I have, It was very useful for calculating CI for NPS, but I think my question is more related to the data acquisition method I am using.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with NPS is that it’s usually calculated as a ratio (prom - det) / # surveys. This doesn’t lend itself to a CI unless you want to analyze raw opinion rankings. You can use a bootstrap approach to estimate confidence intervals around NPS %, then compare across groups, etc.

Comment: Yes as a difference in proportions the sampling distribution is normally distributed, hence bootstrap and CI work as usual. But will this sampling method would yield a valid random sample?